# Error symbols not showing in vim-syntastic

Tags: vim, syntastic, vim-syntastic

I am trying to add custom error symbols to `syntastic` in my `.vimrc` file as so:

```
" Error symbols
let g:syntastic_error_symbol = "✗"
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol ="∙∙"
```

But I think I have managed to break something. Now not even the default symbols are loading properly but I instead get `S>` instead of `>>` on the left-hand-side margin.

So not only cannot I not get my custom symbols, neither can I get the default ones. What happened?

The full syntastic settings are:

```
" ============== syntastic settings ===============
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

" Specific checkers for tex
let g:syntastic_tex_checkers = ['chktex', 'proselint']

" Others
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 1

" Error symbols
" let g:syntastic_error_symbol = "✗"
" let g:syntastic_warning_symbol ="∙∙"
```

Comment: There are four symbols to set: `syntastic_error_symbol`, `syntastic_style_error_symbol`, `syntastic_warning_symbol`, and `syntastic_style_warning_symbol`.  See also the [FAQ](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqstyle).

Comment: @Icd047 - what is the difference between all of those?

Comment: Signs for syntax checkers vs. signs for style checkers. It's all in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
" Error symbols 
let g:syntastic_error_symbol = "✗"
let syntastic_style_error_symbol = "✗"
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = "∙∙"
let syntastic_style_warning_symbol = "∙∙"
```